# Can you search a tree even though it's not a binary search tree?

Tags: tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

A question I'm grappling with in my class. In my view it should be impossible to search a tree not organized for searching like a binary search tree is, at least not without traversing the entire tree? Is there are a more effecient way, or would the only way be to traverse the tree at random, and hope you get lucky

Comment: You are right. If a tree is just randomly organised, it offers no benefit for finding a value in it compared to finding it in an unsorted array.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "search a tree".   Do you mean, for example, that the nodes are attributed (e.g., with a name) and you're looking for the node that has a specific value (e.g., name)?   In that case, the structure of the tree does not matter.

Comment: Ok, yes that is what I mean. lets say I want to search for a value in a tree. In a binary search tree that is a simple matter. But how would that work in a tree that is not organized for searching, or a tree that might not even be a binary tree?

Comment: You have answered your own question: you cannot benefit from such unorganized tree structure: you'll have to traverse the whole tree, up to the point where you find the value. But in the worst case you'll not find it, or only find it in the last node being visited. It is not much different then from searching a value in an unsorted array.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no efficient way to search an unorganised tree. You can use any kind of traversal to visit one node after the other, without any guarantee that you will quickly find the value. It might be that you only find it at the last node being visited, or not at all.

In that sense it is no different from searching a value in an unsorted array.

For traversal orders you can choose any you want. There is no difference in time complexity: O(n). Some common traversals are:

- Depth-first:

  - preorder: first visit the root, and then traverse the child-subtrees, each with a preorder traversal.
  - postorder: first traverse the child-subtrees, each with a postorder traversal, and then finally visit the root.
  - In case it is a binary tree: inorder: first traverse the left subtree, then visit the root, then traverse the right subtree
- Breadth-first:

  - top down: traverse each level of the tree from top to bottom
  - bottom up: traverse each level of the tree from bottom to top (not so common)

But you can invent other traversals, making sure they visit every node exactly once.